# Custom Search within a Ligtning Component on an array of Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, search

I have a component where I am displaying a list of records querying using APex and displaying data using aura:iteration. I now want to add a search bar so users can search from the aura iteration without making another trip to the server, similar to the standard search in List Views.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
            <!--Search for reports-->
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-lookup" data-select="single">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:search" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" alternativeText="Search" class="slds-input__icon" />
                        <ui:inputText value="{!v.searchText}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dnd-table" ondrop="{!c.handleDrop2}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.leftCol}" var="tableRow">
                    <div id="{!tableRow.Id}" class="dnd-table-row" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.handleDrag}">

                        <lightning:layoutItem  padding="around-small" size="12" largeDeviceSize="6" flexibility="grow">
                            <lightning:card>
                                {!tableRow.Name}
                            </lightning:card>
                        </lightning:layoutItem>  

                    </div>
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>
```

Comment: [How TO - Filter/Search List](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

Comment: It works now Thanks to the GitHub link by @sfdxfox. But It only works the first time. So When I search for something, it shows me those rows but when I delete the search and search for something else, it doesn't show m the updated list. Shoudn't the Aura handler with change fire everytime I change the search parameter?